# how to override ListView Items Property without creating new control?

Tags: c#

how to override ListView Items Property without creating new control ?

Comment: what platform? asp? wpf? winforms? we need more information.

Comment: I do not want to create a new user control that override ListView .

I only want to override Items from one ListView .

I using .net 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be setting ListView.Items as necessary, instead of overriding the property. If you are updating it too often, check ListView.BeginUpdate and ListView.EndUpdate.

*Edit*: after all, setting ListView.Items changes ListView.Text as well, and vice versa. There are other compilications too.